# Probability of 30 Die Rolls

Tags: probability

> A die is rolled 30 times with the upper face being what is observed.
>
> a. Find the probability that each of the six sides shows up exactly five times.
>
> b. Find the probability that the die shows a 1 exactly five times and a 2 exactly 10 times.

Part a I know the probability of a 1,2,3...6 are all $\frac{1}{6}$.  Since we want each to been 5 times in 30 rolls then we would do $(\frac{1}{6})^{30}$ and that would be the probability for part a, I believe that is correct.

For part b I am a little more confused.  I think it's possible I need to use binomial distribution but I have not learned that yet so I am trying to figure out a more simple way, or basic form of probability to solve this.

Comment: You should be using the multinomial distribution for both parts.  Your answer of $\frac{1}{6^{30}}$ is the answer to the different problem of what the probability is that you throw the dice in sequence and get very precisely five 1's followed by five 2's followed by five 3's and so on... but for our question we didn't care in what order they appeared

Comment: I got the term binomial distribution from the internet since I just started studying probability so I wasn't 100% sure, which leads me to my question what is multinomial distribution?  I am new to the study of probability so terms like that I have not heard of.  Your explanation makes sense though of why it wouldn't be what I did.

Comment: The multinomial distribution is just the binomial distribution but rather than only two possibilities for each trial and asking for $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures, we have many possibilities and we are asking for the probability of getting precisely $a_1$ results of the first type, $a_2$ results of the second type, $a_3$ results of the third type, and so on...  Given probability $p_i$ of getting a result of the $i$'th type, the probability of getting $a_1$ of first, $a_2$ of second, etc... will be $\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots}p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\cdots$

Comment: So, for your problem $\binom{30}{5,5,5,5,5,5}\cdot \frac{1}{6^5}\cdot\frac{1}{6^5}\cdots \frac{1}{6^5}=\frac{30!}{(5!)^66^{30}}$.  Read more about it [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, $\left(\frac16\right)^{30}$ is the probability to have a precise sequence of number. Like getting five $1$, then five $2$, etc. What you need to add is where are each $1$, where are each $2$, etc.

Lets start with the $1$'s, there are $30$ die and $5$ of them show a $1$, we need to choose $5$ in $30$. Then the $2$', there are $25$ die left, and we need to choose $5$.  The number of ways the $30$ die will show five of each sides is
$${30\choose5}{25\choose5}{20\choose5}{15\choose5}{10\choose5}{5\choose5}=\frac{30!}{5!\times5!\times5!\times5!\times5!\times5!}$$
The right hand side of this equation is called the multinomial coefficient.

Each of these possibilities has a probability of $\left(\frac16\right)^{30}$, hence your probability is
$$\frac{30!}{(5!)^6\times6^{30}}$$

A simila argument is made for part b.First choose the five die that show a $1$, then the ten die that show a $2$, the rest could be anything but $1$ or $2$.
$${30\choose5}\times\left(\frac16\right)^5\times{25\choose10}\times\left(\frac16\right)^{10}\times\left(\frac46\right)^{15}$$